# C++ thread lambda captured object can read but cannot erase

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I'm new in c++ so my problem could be very simple but I cannot solve it.
In my constructor I want to start detached thread which will be looping with class variable and removing old data.
**userCache.hpp**

```
struct UserCacheItem {
    long m_expires;
    oatpp::Object<User> m_user;

    UserCacheItem(const long expires, const oatpp::Object<User> &user);
};

class UserCache {
private:

    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<UserCacheItem> > m_userCacheItem;

public:
    UserCache();

    void cacheUser(std::string payload, std::shared_ptr<UserCacheItem> &userCacheItem);
};
```

**userCache.cpp**

```
UserCache::UserCache()
{
    std::thread thread([this]() mutable {
        while (true){
            auto curTimestamp = std::chrono::seconds(std::chrono::seconds(std::time(nullptr))).count();

            for(auto &elem : m_userCacheItem){
                if (curTimestamp > elem.second->m_expires){
                    std::cout << "Erasing element: " << elem.second->m_expires << std::endl;
                    m_userCacheItem.clear();
                }
            }

            std::cout << "Cache size: " << m_userCacheItem.size() << " Current timestamp: " << curTimestamp << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        };
    });
    thread.detach();
}
```

When I reach line `m_userCacheItem.clear();` I get segmentation fault. Ofcourse if *if* block is false  line with cout cache sizie is printed properly.
So I can read my variable but I cannot modify it :(

Where I'm making error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Why do you call this copy constructor `std::chrono::seconds(std::chrono::seconds(std::time(nullptr)))`?

Comment: this is in oat++ framork written and it will be difficult to provide some reproduce example :(

Comment: You cannot modify the map while you're iterating it with the for loop

Comment: @ThomasSablik I call this, because I need current timestamp to check if objects in cache are still fresh

Comment: @PirklW this is it. Thanks. Outside the loop it clears :) Thank you.

Comment: You convert `std::time(nullptr)` to `std::chrono::seconds` with `std::chrono::seconds(std::time(nullptr))` and then you convert the `std::chrono::seconds` to `std::chrono::seconds` with `std::chrono::seconds(std::chrono::seconds(std::time(nullptr)))` because you need the current timestamp? Could you please explain. That makes absolutely no sense for me.

Comment: I added an answer just in case

Comment: @ThomasSablik that conversion I found on stackoverflow as I remember well. So please tell me, what syntax is correct to get current timestamp?

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds(std::time(nullptr)).count()` but that sounds like [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You should try to understand the code and not blindly copy and paste it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify the map while you're iterating it

```
            for(auto &elem : m_userCacheItem){
                if (curTimestamp > elem.second->m_expires){
                    std::cout << "Erasing element: " << elem.second->m_expires << std::endl;
                    m_userCacheItem.clear();
                }
            }
```

If you want to erase an element, use std::map::erase:

```
for(auto & it = m_userCacheItem.begin(); it != m_userCacheItem.end();) {
    if(condition) {
        it = m_userCacheItem.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```